# value replacement in pandas in multiple coulmn

Tags: replace

[i want to replace all the numeric values by 1 except 0.
i am creating a matrix of zero and one. where zero is Nan and 1 is any number which is 1 or greater than one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVUSy.png)

Comment: To replace a column for all numerics values except 0 we do something like this. 
df.loc[(df.col != 0),'col']=1in panda.

Comment: what is 'col' here?

Comment: col would be your column name.

Comment: i have 714 columns. Can't specify all of them at once.

Comment: i have used this code.
`df[df[:]>=1]=1`

its perfectly working the way  i wanted